# How to upload files with react to my .net server

Tags: asp.net, file, reactjs, axios

How do I upload images to my server. I am using react and so far my controller looks like this:

```
 [Authorize]
 public object UploadAvatar()
{
            var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;
}
```

file shows = null when I am upload with react and axios:

```
const URL = '/api/userapi/uploadavatar';
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = e.target.files[0];
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = (upload) => {
  console.log(upload.target.result);
  axios.post(URL, {
    data: upload.target.result
  }, config);
}
```

**But when i upload with postman it works fine**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just post the file object like this:

```
const URL = '/api/userapi/uploadavatar';
var file = e.target.files[0];
axios.post(URL, {data: file});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few components to upload files in React, for instance:

http://okonet.ru/react-dropzone/

https://github.com/lionng429/react-file-uploader